# BigQuery Split dataset bias

Tags: machine-learning, google-bigquery, data-science

A good example from [oreilly's article](https://www.oreilly.com/learning/repeatable-sampling-of-data-sets-in-bigquery-for-machine-learning) for the airline ontime dataset ML case.
The query is following in order to select 80% of records for training.

```
SELECT
  date,
  airline,
  departure_airport,
  departure_schedule,
  arrival_airport,
  arrival_delay
FROM
  [bigquery-samples:airline_ontime_data.flights]
WHERE
  ABS(HASH(date)) % 10 < 8
```

As far as I concerned, the date is not unique.
Let's say if 30% of the flight are all at a specific day(this is not a best example, the other dataset could fit into this scenario better), then the hash value for this is always the same.
If we mod them with 10 the 30% of the record will either stay in <8 sides or >=8 side.

If my understanding is correct and this query does cause bias, is there any other better way to split the dataset to 80/10/10?

Comment: What is the best way to split nonuniformly distributed dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the article assumes that dates are uniformly distributed, which may not be true. You can instead fingerprint the contents of the row directly:

```
SELECT
  date,
  airline,
  departure_airport,
  departure_schedule,
  arrival_airport,
  arrival_delay
FROM
  `bigquery-samples`.airline_ontime_data.flights
WHERE
  MOD(ABS(FARM_FINGERPRINT(TO_JSON_STRING(flights))), 10) < 8
```

Note that this query uses standard SQL instead of legacy SQL. If you're using the standalone classic BigQuery UI, uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" in the options menu before running it.

Comment: Yes, the original code is using Legacy SQL. In other words the best way to split data is split by PK? (while BigQuery doesn't have PK so I would say unique column?)

Comment: The example that I provided doesn't depend on having one column with distinct values; it depends on having distinct values across rows. But yes, you need some way of getting different (deterministic) hash values across rows, and this is a solution.